# How to use EF5 to select items where ID is in list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've tried every combination that I can think of... using Any, Contains, etc... and cannot get any to work.  I need to pull back all objects in a single table using EF5 where the ID(PK) is in an array of values.

This is the singular call:

```
items = context.DiscoveryDevices.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.DiscoveryIdentifier.Equals(discoveryIdentifier, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

I basically need to send in an array of "discoveryIdentifier" (string[] discoveryIdentifiers) and return multiple objects.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
items = context.DiscoveryDevices.AsNoTracking().Where(x =>
                discoveryIdentifiers.Contains(x.DiscoveryIdentifier, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think IList.Contains() should work here.

```
IList<String> listOfIdentifiers;
var items = context.DiscoveryDevices.AsNoTracking().Where(x => listOfIdentifiers.Contains(x.DiscoveryIdentifier)).ToList();
```

Comment: Nooo... can't be.  Where the ARRAY CONTAINS the PK.  That's the complete opposite of the actual SQL statement.  Interesting.

Comment: This did not work.  I received an error...  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.